Fine tuning: TikZ, pgfplots and Lennard-Jones potential
I'm trying to recreate a faithful copy of the graph shown here.

I'm trying and trying again, but I would like to make the curve tend to infinity more quickly for x=0 and tend to 0 more quickly for x=infinity.
My MWE:
\documentclass[14pt]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[natbib=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{./refs.bib}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\eps}{4}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\sig}{1.1}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\min}{1}
        \pgfmathdeclarefunction{V}{1}{%
          \pgfmathparse{%
             4*\eps*((\sig/#1)^12-(\sig/#1)^6)
            }%
        }
        \begin{axis}[
            samples=2000,
            restrict y to domain =-50:100,xmin=\min,xmax=2,ymin=-6,ymax=10
        ];
            \addplot[very thick,blue,domain=\min:50] plot {V(x)};
            \addplot[dotted,domain=20:50] plot {0};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}



Increase x-domain. The curve will shrink, which looks more like you want.

For this type of diagram, sometimes it is easier just to draw the path as a Bezier curve instead of a real function.   Here is an effort in Metapost, but if you are committed to TikZ, I believe that you can do similar things with the Hobby package.

You need to compile this with lualatex.  Follow the first link above for MP tutorials and reference manuals.
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);

  numeric u; u = 34;

  path xx, yy;
  yy = (2.7 down -- 4.2 up) scaled u;
  xx = origin -- 10 right scaled u;
  xx := xx shifted point 0 of yy;

  path p;
  p = ((.7, 4){dir -89} .. (1, 0) .. (2.5, -2) {right} .. (5, -1) ... (10, 0) {right}) scaled u;

  path a, b, c;
  a = (xpart point 1 of p, ypart point 0 of p) -- point 1 of p -- point 4 of p;
  b = (0, ypart point 1 of p) -- point 1 of p -- (xpart point 1 of p, ypart point 0 of xx);
  c = (0, ypart point 2 of p) -- point 2 of p -- (xpart point 2 of p, ypart point 0 of xx);

  draw a; 
  draw b dashed evenly scaled 1/2;
  draw c dashed evenly scaled 1/2;

  draw xx;
  draw yy;

  draw p withpen pencircle scaled 3/4 withcolor 2/3 red;

  label.lft("$0$", point 0 of b); 
  label.lft("$-\varepsilon$", point 0 of c); 

  label.bot("$\strut\sigma_{AB}$", point 2 of b);
  label.bot("$\strut r^*_{AB}$", point 2 of c);

  label(TEX("\textbf{Energy}") rotated 90, point 1/2 of yy shifted 24 left);
  label("$\mathbf{r_{AB}}$", point 1/2 of xx shifted 24 down);

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}

